# How to perform actions based on user logins in Salesforce without a Login Flow?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

I need to perform certain actions or notifications whenever a user logs into Salesforce. However, it seems that creating a trigger directly on the LoginEvent object is not possible in Salesforce.

I have explored other options such as login flows and custom Visualforce pages, but they require user interaction or are not suitable for applying the functionality to every user.(As login flow requires Profiles, however I need to run it for every user)

Is there an alternative approach or workaround to achieve this requirement? I want to perform actions automatically for every user login without relying on profiles or requiring user interaction.

I have looked into Login Event Monitoring, which captures login-related events and logs them as LoginEvent records. However, I couldn't find a way to create a trigger on the LoginEvent object to execute actions based on login events.

Any insights or suggestions on how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Transaction Security](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_transaction_security_policy_apex_examples.htm&type=5)? There's a decent trailhead course too: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/enhanced_transaction_security/enhanced_transaction_security_basics

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to Transaction Security in my sandbox, I've created a apex that has the business logic and sending Notification. Just need to trigger the apex on login of any user in the org.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_loginevent.htm requires shield too. Make a case to buy the event monitoring addon (business might reject it but it's the right solution) and I think your only option is flow / vf page. You could have some reusable sub0flow or vf component you embed on these... clone them quickly by copy-pasting files in VSCode?

Comment: Thanks @eyescream, it seems this is the only solution then, my only problem is to do it for every profile. Although thank you so much for putting in efforts.